# Recommended way to serve PyTorch predictions with Google AI Platform

Tags: pytorch, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

Reading through Google's documentation, it seems there are two different ways of serving predictions form PyTorch models.

1. [Using custom prediction routines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#tensorflow)
2. [Creating a custom container and using `torchserve`](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/getting-started-pytorch-container)

Although option 1 seems more popular from reading through online blogs such as [this one](https://medium.com/searce/deploy-your-own-custom-model-on-gcps-ai-platform-7e42a5721b43), it seems weird to not use option 2 since the documentation explicitly mentions PyTorch.

Can anyone provide why one might choose one option over another?

Answer (score 0):

1 is simpler in that you don't have to worry about creating an http handler, but it's probably harder for you to test with locally.

2 you build your own container and so you can try running it on your local first. It's slightly more work because you have to be able to set up a http handler.